# Serial Deletion: To infinity... and beyond!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, serial-voting, vote-to-delete

This question comes after *a lot* of flagging by me to reverse illegitimate deletions (e.g.: [Does the string contain ASCII zenkaku?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18588207/1654265) undeleted by a Moderator because it is clearly legit, then reopened).

The deletions always come from the same user; I like to think that he's just acting very strictly, but in good faith, thinking he is making StackOverflow a better place by removing crappy questions. In this case, then he might just need a a recalibration of which questions should be considered crappy, and which legit. Otherwise, I guess it's abuse.

I don't care if crappy questions I've answered get deleted (I've got dozens of them); it was my fault to answer those questions, so even if the OP tried hard, showed an attempt, but in the end it turned out to be a typo, or a naïve question, it absolutely deserved the deletion. I comment now instead of answering, in those cases.

But can you please express your opinion: are these questions (the latest in the series) worthy of deletion (They've now been undeleted, so you can see them even if < 10K)?

1. [Does the Struts2 DateTimePicker allow to input dates and times with a specific Locale and Timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28580134/1654265) :
   asked by a new user, in a not crystal clear way, but IMHO understandable and legit... "does the S2 datetimepicker allow to input a date and a time with a different timezone from the one used by the application ?" And the answer is "no, but there are alternatives", and a brief overview of the best practices. The user has not even logged in since then, so our requests for clarification cannot be fulfilled by him, because of the deletion. Only 1 of the 4 users closing the question has [struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts2) tags. The 2 users deleting it have ZERO [struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts2) tags *.
2. [There is no result type defined for type 'redirect-action' mapped with name 'success'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15243002/1654265) : this is amazing. The question is closed because of the following reason:

   > This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**.

   Nothing could be further from the reality. That is a PERFECTLY VALID syntax for older versions of Struts2, that has been deprecated in newer versions. It is not a typo, nor a problem that can no longer be reproduced. Instead, this is a problem that many people following old crappy tutorials, or migrating old Struts2 software to the latest libraries encounter every day. Deleting this is like deleting a Spring 2.5 question because now there is Spring 4 out, and 2.5 syntax is now considered a typo. ALL the users closing it, and ALL the users deleting it have ZERO [struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts2) tags *.

Please, express your opinion on the two questions above: which is legit, the questions or the deletions ?

---

[*] This is another problem, people (with tiny to huge reputations) closing and deleting questions on technologies they do not even remotely know, and that they barely read, just for badge hunting... leaving the original caster the responsibility to choose to close-vote and delete-vote only questions really deserving it. This is the reason that led me to stop following those review queues... it was too long for me to check every single question / answer, and I refuse to close or delete potentially legit questions, just because "I can".

Then here is the secondary purpose of this question: ***I'd like to propose that at least the Deletion Queue should allow a user to delete a question only if the user has a minimal number of tags on each tag involved, proving he knows what he is doing.***

Otherwise, expect the Deletion "Queue" to raise *to infinity... and beyond !*

[image: Buzz Lightyear]

Comment: Your "question" feels very ranty. If you have a problem with one single user, then meta is not the best place to solve it  - talk to them in chat and try to sort it out, ignore them, or contact mods in extreme cases. As for "unlegit" closure and deletion: many users VTC/delete crap on sight, no matter if it might be answerable - the definition of "crap" varies by user, but in general a question should be nontrivial and useful for googlers having a similar problem. Anyways, if "hundreds" of your answers are on deleted questions, maybe _you_ have a problem of answering too many crap questions?

Comment: The hyperbole drips off the page.  It is just one user, he's only got one vote.  Big whoopie.  It takes six more users to get a question deleted.

Comment: Limiting close or delete voting to those with answers in the tags is not going to scale. At all. There are too many niches out there and too few people with enough knowledge in those niches for crap in such tags to achieve enough close votes. If you have a problem with specific posts being deleted, use a moderator flag to try and get it undeleted.

Comment: I agree with Hans and l4mpi here that the *tone* of your post is not going to help your cause either. You are effectively targeting specific users with innuendo and conjecture. Please do read the [help/behavior] on how we hope people will behave here, which includes *assume good intentions*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even moderators are noticing the same names pop up on votes to delete; we're also noticing that a non-trivial amount of those questions should not have been deleted.  The OP does a bad job of actually sussing that out (they don't easily have the capability to figure out what a user deletes), but they're not wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Right, so the OP is shooting themselves in the foot here with the tone then.

Comment: @l4mpi : I've hundreds of good answers to good questions that are now marked for deletion. They're in queue since *a lot*, but I didn't care because I thought that they'd be refused by the other users voting for deletion. Since now average-quality questions are starting to get deleted instead, I'm becoming worried. BTW, `maybe you have a problem of answering too many crap questions` I've opened this to ask you if you considered the two above questions worth deletion. Do you ?

Comment: @HansPassant exactly: the hyperbole is that it's a single user, and six more votes are needed... so why are questions not needing (if not) to be deleted, getting deleted ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are definitely right, this *is* ranty ("*I don't like to seem ranty, and this is why I've waited more than a year, but this is going too far*") but please, consider two years of stalking, a lot of flags to moderators, a lot of "this will hopefully not occour again", and now the user is > 20K, and soon or later he'll get the gold badge in the tag... I mean, **if he is deleting questions not deserving it**, no matter why (to damage me, or to do what *he think* is right), someone has to tell him, and that someone is the Community. He'll listen to you big users, MAYBE...

Comment: @AndreaLigios: sounds like the moderators and community team are already aware of the behaviour; this kind of problem needs to be handled at their level. If they already talked to the user, I doubt more talk by users (high rep or otherwise) is going to help.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: I disagree this needs to be public.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, I've refactored the question in a more aseptic and non-ranty way. Hope is more general purpose now

Comment: Note that there is *no review queue for deletion*. 10k+ users can see a listing of top deletion votes, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: I know, it's my fault for miscalling it, "listing of top deletion votes" or something like that was too verbose in the text and I opted for "queue", even if it's not exactly a queue (nor it provides badges, that part was related to close-vote queue).

Comment: Re "Do you?": Now that I can see the questions, I'm actually on the edge for both of them; can't give a definitive answer as I'm not a Struts expert. The "redirectAction" one would depend on how well-documented that is; as an analogy I'd be all for deleting every single python3 question that asks about a failing `print` without parens. The timezone one seems broad and you've acknowledged in the edit comment it's "an edge case" (potentially an X/Y? Should definitely have more input from OP); the answer also feels lacking as it starts about ux and doesn't even address the core q until later.

Comment: @l4mpi : until some months ago, Struts2 documentation was duplicated divided per minor version: the same page was present per 2.0.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x, 2.3.x. This syntax was present in 2.0 and (if I recall well) 2.1 versions. Today (2015) all the Struts2 documentation has been merged into a version-agnostic documentation, covering only the edge case, with some alert for previous versions. It was definitely mentioned in the docs, and it was definitely the right syntax for 2.0. It's not some missing parens at all :/

Comment: @l4mpi : the other question is not an X/Y (I know it well, I point it out any time I see one), and even if it's an edge case, should it be removed for that ? :| A common bad practice is to use the old integrated Dojo tags, replaced by the new plugin jQuery tags, and this is the first part of the question; then nowadays you should always prefer the HTML5 default with 3rd party libraries as fallbacks, and that's in the middle; at last, to achieve the specific use case, there are alternative libraries, and that's the final part. It's a progression, to try helping future readers on the subject...

Comment: You misunderstood - I meant how well the _change_ was documented. In my python example, anybody who spends 20 seconds reading up on the differences between python2 and python3 would know that `print` became a function in python3 (and anybody knowing the python basics thus knows they can't use the statement syntax of python2). If the documentation of the version breaking the old syntax is accessible and clearly states the change, then I'd personally be in favour of deletion as it falls under "trivial" and I see no use in duplicating that information; even though it's ok by SO policy.

Comment: It's what I'm telling you: it is not accessible anymore, or not easily, because I've searched it now, knowing that it exists (or existed), and I've not found it. Maybe it's still there, hidden, or maybe is gone. BTW that is not a typo and when I've encountered that, I've solved it "by guts" changing the syntax, but it would have been helpful to find it in a SO answer

Comment: Do the docs cover all possible result types? If so, it still feels trivial: wrong type? Simply check which are defined. Btw, your "progression" in the other answer does not feel helpful (from a perspective of not knowing struts); you've edited the _question_ to ask about a specific date picker and then present all date picker options in the answer. A good idea would be to _start_ the answer by answering the question: "No, there are none except for third party libraries and this barely supported html5 feature". Then continue on with whatever you like.

Comment: With your first sentence, that is RTFM, almost 9 out of 10 questions on stackoverflow could not been asked at all, or deleted. There are very few things not in the manuals that are asked and answered by someone having discovered them on the field. About the other answer, I've edited the question but not changed anything: OP asked about the datetimepicker tagging it struts2, so waiting for it to return, I've added Struts2 in the text. There is only one S2 datetimepicker. For the rest, it's not a great answer, but I hope it's not useless, and 2 other people thinks the same. BTW thanks

Comment: @l4mpi BTW I've followed your suggestion and refactored the datetimepicker answer to first answer the question, then widen the field of view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not singling l4mpi out; but his comment on your question shows us the issue:

> many users VTC/delete crap on sight, no matter if it might be answerable - the definition of "crap" varies by user, *but in general a question should be nontrivial* and useful for googlers having a similar problem.

It seems like a fair two part criteria, doesn't it?

- Question should be non-trivial
- Useful for future visitors

I argue that the second part is the important piece. Technical difficulty should not enter into the equation at all.  The amount of questions that are so baldly easy that they merit closing on those accounts are so few and far between that there's no need to institute a technical bar for asking.

Why?

I'll let Jeff take it from here:

> Stackoverflow is sort of like the anti-experts-exchange (minus the nausea-inducing sleaze and quasi-legal search engine gaming) meets wikipedia meets programming reddit. It is by programmers, for programmers, **with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world.** No matter what programming language you use, or what operating system you call home. Better programming is our goal.

That means that when it comes to deleting posts, we should really ask a two part question:

1. Does this question and its associated answers contribute to the sum of good programming knowledge (Good defined as the "right" approach)?
2. If we delete this set of posts, will we have helped our goal or hurt it?

In both cases, due to the efforts by the OP to edit the question into shape and the extraordinary answer provided, these questions should not have been deleted.

As far as your other points, if you believe your posts are being unfairly deleted, please flag and link to the correct posts in your flags. If there's a pattern, we'll suss it out and take appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks for your time and comprehension George Stocker