# To whom do I go when I'm being stalked by a specific user?

Tags: support, serial-voting, specific-user, harassment

I believe that a user is attempting to stalk my activities on Stack Overflow.  They had attempted a large downvoting effort, which was reversed, so instead, they are resorted to downvoting me once a day.  What can I do to notify diamond moderators about this user who seems to be harassing me through targeted voting of my questions and answers, and/or has been doing so over a long period of time?

Comment: Fwiw the user involved has already been suspended.

Comment: Having to put up with someone harassing you on a site that you're actively  participating on *for years* sounds like it really sucks.

Comment: Don't worry, you're not the only one who's taken issue with him for years.

Comment: Surely this could have just been resolved with a moderator flag? Did moderators not get involved when the harrassment first started?

Comment: @halfer: Ever heard of repeat offenders?

Comment: @BoltClock: sure, of course - I am very supportive of it being resolved, and the OP has my genuine sympathy. I'm just expressing mild surprise that a very high rep user brought it to _Meta_, that's all.

Comment: @halfer maybe that's what's needed this time...

Comment: @halfer: See Cupcake's comment.

Comment: I know I'm being whiny, but IMO it's been egregious, literally for years, and I'm not the sole victim-there's a small group of us that are frustrated. I apologize for the whine. Consider it a class-action SO suit.

Comment: @Cupcake As petty and juvenile as it sounds, it's really been a downer :/

Comment: @Dave Newton: I'd call having to put up with things and people you shouldn't have to anything but petty or juvenile.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how can you tell that it is one specific person?

Comment: @enki.dev Historical precedence based on when disagreements start and the next few days of rep changes. It's *possible* I'm incorrect, but I'd be surprised if I was this time. My rep changes slowly, but fairly predictably over time: changes to that pattern, coupled with several recent incidents, leads me to believe it's the same user, yet again.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't doubt that you're right,  I was just curious if MODs had the ability to see who was up voting and down voting.

Comment: Hi @Dave. I didn't mean to imply you're whining - I am not of that opinion - just that unless there's an answerable question on _Meta_, it is hard for non-mods to give anything but general advice. Of course, if you call the user out in particular, that can create other problems. Nevertheless, folks above believe there was justification to bring it here, and I suspect they know what they're talking about `:-)`. Hope you get it resolved soon.

Comment: @halfer No offense taken-and I *am* whining! Honestly, it was really just venting, because it's been going on for so long, and it's one of the reasons I dread answering questions in a tag I *should* be answering questions in :/ The responses here have been better than my whine deserved.

Comment: I find this very interesting, he's just downvoting 1 answer or so every day and its been going on for years? Doesn't that come to 1k of your rep.. compared to the 107k you have.. @JohnnyBones just posted the same thing I was headed too - Is there more to the harassment than just voting?

Comment: Several times I've started bounties, and there were bounty hunters with one line answers that had nothing in common with the question. Those answers magically got 2 upvotes, and my rep was automatically stolen. I was so angry that I've thought to stalk these guys downvoting one answer a day, but I was sure StackOverflow had scripts for such behaviour too. You guys have totally saved my day.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph um, that sounds like those users were committing voting-fraud and using sock-puppets...

Comment: You could change your nickname here for a month; that might shake them off.  Ideally serial-downvoting-detection would protect user a from user b no matter how slowly the downvoting occurs; is that the case?

Comment: This whole thread feels as though everyone knows/should know who this *specific user* is/was. Any clues for us who don't?

Comment: Just as much as we don't need stalkers and harassers @Keale, we don't need lynch mobs. Those who can handle this know. And that's enough.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227845/214186

Comment: @AndreaLigios Hadn't seen that post, obviously I'm on board. This was after the tagging issue? I lose track of all the stupidity around our good, long-term friend :/

Comment: @DaveNewton, nope, that post is from one year and a half ago. And for what I've been able to got at that time, only 1/4 of the downvotes circa came from *him*. I've never known who was the other, major stalker. Now more than one year has passed, but here we are, again. What can I say... History repeats itself, appearently.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The standard procedure for dealing with serial downvoting is [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). For bursts of targeted votes, the system will invalidate them automatically. If the voting is particularly egregious or continues past that point, you can raise a flag about it and moderators will look into it further.

We can only see larger patterns, though, and cannot see individual votes. Stack Exchange employees need to be called in to investigate and invalidate these votes, and their time is very limited. We tend to call them in only in the worst or most obvious cases.

For someone like you, this situation is more complicated. In the case of long-time users who have contributed lots of posts, you will have many people voting more than once on your posts (up or down) just by pure chance. Separating malicious intent from voting based on quality can be harder in this circumstance.

I should say that I suspended one user who had targeted you and other users with serial downvotes yesterday, and they won't be bothering you with those. I've also requested that Stack Exchange employees look into all these votes and invalidate the ones that the script missed. This may take a bit, though, since most of the SE folks are returning from a conference.

I should also note that the account I suspended is not the person I know you are referring to. There may be a connection between the two, but I don't have good enough evidence to act on that yet.

We're well aware of the arguments you have had with the person you are referring to, but I'm not sure that "stalking" is the right term here. Maybe "feud", as I see that in terms of downvotes you've given as good as you've gotten. Again, we're looking into it, but it can sometimes be difficult to see which side is in the wrong for long-running arguments like this. This might take a little bit to sort out.

Comment: why can't we all just get along

Comment: If you have access to "deleted" comments spanning back lo these years IMO it's pretty clear. If course, I'm biased. I did finally start to match his voting behavior (and the literature shows it's a winning strategy ;) Sort of. It's unusual for my rep to take a sustained drain like this, though, AFAICT.

Comment: I'm surprised I have another attacker, though, in general I've not had any major incidents with anybody else I'm aware of :(

Comment: @DaveNewton: I'm being stalked too. This time it is not the person you are referring to, because, 1) if you take a look at his rep, he is being stalked too (!), and 2) he knows *exactly* how the reversal script works, while this new troll doesn't: he/she started serial downvoting, then after the script, he/she started serial downvoting slower. NOTE: I've checked all the delete-votes, close-votes, "bad" comments left by me up to the 10 days BEFORE the stalk began and... found nothing. This idiot has jumped out of nowhere, maybe from months ago. I'm very curious to know who he is. Stay tuned.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: This could be intentional.

Comment: @AndreaLigios We must be special. Who knew that tag could be so dangerous!

Comment: @AleksandrM: if you are suggesting that it could effectively be the same user, that has created and grown up another account (or is just using a friend's account), and that downvoted us AND himself just to mislead us, by intentionally triggering the reversal script the first time *as a diversion*, well... it's embarassing but I admit I've thought it at first :D , at least as a possibility. I just refuse to think that a professor, who has lived half of a century, can go this far in a flame-war that the others aren't even playing. But who knows, people is crazy, it may be. I hope not, though

Comment: @AndreaLigios I think that happened long enough ago, but... as we know, grudges are held onto tightly by some people. It's just annoying :( It sucked the joy out of the S2 tag. I just can't wrap my head around that kind of behavior no matter who it is. I admit I'm over-sensitive, but it just ruins SO for me some days.

Comment: @Andrea Ligios: We'd rather not talk publicly about it. No need to add fuel to the fire by linking to posts and profiles.

Comment: Ok @BoltClock, I'll remove the link. IF BTW the whole thing will end in that direction... it will be very disappointing. It's years now... an user over 20k stalking other users *for years*. Bleah

Comment: IF the latter hypothesized case is true, then I could have found the culprit (link removed). I edited the meta question (this seems to pisses him off) while you last-edited the original question by removing the tags he was seeking. Not sure why AleksandrM is not targeted too, but they've had a lot less issues than him with me and you. BradLarson: I know you can't tell us who you suspended, but... can you tell us if he registered later than October, 2 ? (it could have been created earlier, though)

Comment: @BoltClock 'cause internet.

Comment: @DaveNewton he does'nt seem to be him in the end. He's got even more downvotes than us, up to yesterday :|

Comment: @BradLarson for the record, does this have something to do with it ? Is it the same guy, one year later ? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251908/214186

Comment: @AndreaLigios - Yes, this appears to be related. I'm not sure it was triggered by the event you mentioned on October 2, since it started before that and happened again several days after that. As with then, there's a lot of noise here and it may take an SE employee to sort this out.

Comment: I thought an SE employee was already on this :| BTW let's see what happens, thanks, I won't bother you again (unless receiving further downvotes :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios I'm still not convinced, actually, since it's a few specific users being targeted, namely us :p I dunno. Even if it isn't the same person, I'm at the point of wanting a perma-ban :/

Comment: @BradLarson *"(unless receiving further downvotes :)"* you might have noticed I've started flagging again for serial downvoting and [serial deletion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286717/1654265) :( I would really opt for a flag on your db to remove the voting capability from users like this one. Boolean can_vote {'Y'/'N'}. Ex convicts can't vote, why users suspended multiple times (and still stalking) should ? They should be able to ask and to answer, not to vote, imho. I'm a hard-liner now, thanks to this guy. To hell with him. Sorry for the whine, but I'm overly pissed off.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Did you check the profile lately? Just noticed a change today, but it could have happened earlier. I'm mostly happy, but... I'd rather see behavioral change. *hahahahahaha* Hey, could happen :p It *has* been supremely irritating, and for so long :/

Comment: @DaveNewton It's from this morning (or yesterday evening, can't remember). I've been stalked a lot *after* you opened this, flagged everything, this is the result. But both the first stalker's downvotes and his downvotes are NOT being reverted, yet, and I'm not sure if they'll ever be. So annoying

Comment: @AndreaLigios - I'll point out that there is a huge backlog of vote review requests that SE employees are working through, which piled up during their all-hands meeting and from a series of voting rings we had broken down before that.  All of that has to be done by hand by an SE employee and is very time-consuming. It may take them a bit to work through all of this, which is why I said this will take a while to sort out. The overall problem has been dealt with, and you won't see additional targeted votes going forward.

Comment: @BradLarson Nobody's criticizing :) Although in fairness, I've been griping about this guy for years now :( It's one of the rare occasions where I'm now ok with a perma-ban. If there are shareable details I'd love to hear them off-line--given my history with the guy, I think I deserve it :D

Comment: @BradLarson I'm sure I've not explained myself correctly. I'm absolutely not complaining about the timings; there've just been cases in the past where, on purpose, reversion has not been made, but I guess this won't be one of them. I didn't want to sound whiny, I'm not and I won't be even if votes won't be reversed. *So annoying* was referred to the whole thing, to years of this. Dave: I'm still not good with a permaban for users with 30k rep, that HAVE actually spent time, but heck if I'd not remove him the downvote privilege. Just that, no downvotes, and everybody happy. So simple.

Comment: @AndreaLigios That'd work too. I've noticed a lot less downvotes on the questions in our tag--at one point I thought he was on an active mission to kill the tag off altogether :( *grumble* I dunno. We're being whiny, but we're also right.

Comment: @DaveNewton For the records, the serial downvotes have most likely restarted. The aforamentioned user is still banned so it must be a) the first user whom ban period has ended, or b) a new user created with the purpose to downvote by one of the two banned users, or c) a new stalker or d) something. I guess a) could be verified immediately while b) could be inferred by looking at IP addresses compared to the two aboves, but what great balls of mine. Heck.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Have you seen the latest edits-and-undownvoting? I don't understand it, but now I'm annoyed that his name is on all my posts, whether or not the edits make my answers better :/

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't understand it too :| It's quite creepy to see thousands of edits per day, but you know, I'm a dreamer :P and I hope this is just something good (the undownvoting seems to be the goal, while the annoying editing are just a necessary condition for it). His downvote count was near 6000 last time I checked, now is 3700, and counting... *stay tuned* :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios Must have a lot of extra time on his hands.

Comment: @DaveNewton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753928/how-to-return-a-json-result-with-jsp-in-struts-2/35768522?noredirect=1#comment60025909_35753928

Answer (score 12):

I had someone tell me an interesting approach to remedying behavior such as this a while back, and since then I've had the chance to test this out successfully.

> Upvote, and leave a constructive comment on one or more of the offender's posts.

I know this seems counter-intuitive, but it does work. In my case, after doing this, the user upvoted and left a constructive comment on one of my posts, and I haven't had a downvote since.

This may not work in all situations, but it is worth a try. Remember that we are all humans, and all capable of feeling guilty about our actions.

Comment: Wow, you need general's tactics to broker a truce. SO is a battlefield! Genius solution in any case. Alas if it becomes a known trick, it probably loses its effectiveness soon enough.

Comment: +1 Left a constuctive comment :) ..... Don't mean you are the offender!

Answer (score -16):

It seems to be a common problem here... - my solution? Ignore and flag the guy!

Comment: Ignoring isn't great advice imo...

Comment: By the word "ignoring" I mean "don't feed the troll" (intentionally with a "t") and I actually suggested a solution: FLAG the guy!

Comment: Normally I'd agree (and for me, at least, it hasn't been very common at all). We can't flag people, only posts, which I've done a few times (I think). This has been an extreme case of passive-aggressive abuse, more or less since I've been active on the site.

Comment: Slightly amusing that you got downvoted, given the question :D

Comment: What would be *more* amusing would be if it led to years of hostile comments (occasionally in Russian) and tit-for-tat retribution (although in my case, it's "I didn't think you addressed the question and here's why" vs "I HAS A DOWNVOTE U NOW". *That's* why it's frustrating.

Comment: @DaveNewton ["I HAS A DOWNVOTE U NOW"](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/11940) :D:D:D