# Specific user mass-editing my posts

Tags: discussion

In general the edits are OK.

My issues with him are personal and well-documented. I don't want him associated with my posts. Is my only recourse to go and edit all of them again so at least his name isn't visible?

Aaaand I'm being serial downvoted again, but just questions now. Good times.

I quit.

Comment: *My issues with him are personal* --> At Stack Overflow, we do not target specific users. What are you expecting here? For people to rally up to your cause? You can invite him to chat.

Comment: Roman again I presume, I doubt a moderator can still talk to him. His *name* shouldn't be visible??  Hmm.  That's a battle you no doubt have to win by yourself, really rather best to not fight it because you can't win it.

Comment: Wots this?  Hatfields vs. McCoys V2.0?

Comment: Even if you did that, he could just as easily edit back on top of yours again.

Comment: *My issues with him are personal* Well I think if he knows that and only edits just because of this then I think it's going to get a problem.

Comment: I see that ever undownvoted +2 was edited by the same user, seems like a strong indication, that he just edits it to remove his downvote. But it's just an assumption.

Comment: That user is not editing only your posts, but he is really on a editing spree. check his profile.

Comment: @MartinJames Nope, Dave vs. Same Guy That's Been Multi-Banned Several Times And Has Frustrated Multiple Users For Years.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Think of it this way... your feud has dragged itself to the point where the only thing he can do to even come close to riling you is to make edits that, trivial as they are, at their very worst don't actively decrease the quality of your answers, and at best actually [significantly improve them](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8347581/revisions).

In other words, the only actions he can take against you now are *positive* actions. His name may be associated with your posts, but it's associated with positive contributions to your posts. You've won.

The undownvotes that Rizier123 pointed out in the comments appear to be related as well. It seems the user in question is making these edits to remove their downvotes. And you're not the only one on the receiving end of these edits. Could he have reached an agreement with someone else?

We'll be keeping an eye on this one.

Comment: How only 1 character change is applied (there is 6 character limit).[link](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33308656/3)

Comment: @Sandeep: Users with full editing privs aren't subject to the character limit.

Comment: I don't like his gaming, I don't like his attitude, I don't like *him*. He drove me away from SO. It takes a fair amount of effort to generate this amount of dislike in me. It's great he's reverting his previous behavioral lapses, and maybe he'll be a model citizen moving forward-but I don't like that's he's associated with me in the slightest amount.

Comment: @DaveNewton well, you gave SE the irrevocable rights to edit your posts. If you don't like it maybe SE is not for you.

Comment: @Braiam No, people like *him* aren't for me, *or* for SO. But you're right: SO *isn't* for me anymore, because of the individual in question. And responses like yours spoken without having any clue what the ongoing issue is, and for how long it's gone on, and how many other users have been negatively affected by this person.

Comment: @Braiam - Trust me, there's [more to this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308265/to-whom-do-i-go-when-im-being-stalked-by-a-specific-user) than just a series of edits. The user referenced here has exhausted all of my patience, and if I had any indication that they were violating the rules of the site by doing any of this, they would no longer be welcome to participate here.

Comment: (@Braiam That sounds angrier-at-you than I intended; apologies for that. My point was that there's history here going back years, and it's been very frustrating for some times.)

Comment: @BradLarson Well that sounds like we don't just have a simple question about some edits here, but rather something bigger which is overdue for  too long already?! I and probably also Stack Overflow don't want to lose a [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438992) who **contributed a lot** and also seems like **helped a lot of people**.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yep, Brad's aware of the long-running issues. I suspect most of the mods are at this point, for better or worse ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton Well I'm either too new on SO or just totally missed the total story with this user. But maybe it's good to start with writing down some things like: "What is the goal / With what could you live and enjoy SO", "What are the *real data facts* about this user", "What are the options/possibilities we have here", ... and maybe even *try* to discuss this with the specific user. You can still write a smiley, so I hope you don't got completely demotivated by this user, since Stack Overflow lives from users like you who share their knowledge.

Comment: @Rizier123 This started 3-4 years ago, IIRC. The SE team knows the real data facts about this user, hence the multiple bans over time. I obviously haven't left SO completely, but my participation and enjoyment levels are down, and I'm okay with that. Things change. Maybe even this user did; stranger things have happened.